# Changing NSLayoutConstraint programmatically not working

Tags: ios7, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have a subview inside a view with constraints top,left,bottom,right,width and height. I also have IBOutlet for height constraint. I want to change height constraint programmatically so it grows and push parent views. Problem is when I change constraint's constant it pushes parent view but not expand itself. But if i do it in ui editor it works fine.

White one is subview which i want to expand
[image: white one is subview which i want to expand]

Constraints are here

[image: constraints are here]

Before constraints set[image]

After constraints set with;

```
self.heightConst.constant = 300;
```

[image]

Comment: Validate IBOutlet, your bind not right.

Comment: I checked, it looks like correct.

Comment: You have added bottom constraints for your subview then how can you change the height constraints?

Comment: then how would it pushed parent view to expand?

Comment: can you share simple project for look it?

Answer (score 0):

Base on your 2nd screenshot, you haven't assign your property (heightConst) to your Interface Builder (.xib or .storyboard)

and make sure your property has IBOutlet.
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint*heightConst;